# second order ode45-where to put boundary and initial condition?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

I am solving this equation with ode45 method, $p_0$ is already known:

$4B\dfrac{d^2u}{dr^2}+\dfrac{4B}{r}\dfrac{du}{dr}=\dfrac{dp_0}{dz}$

and I have two conditions,

initial condition: $r=0$: $\dfrac{du}{dr}=0$;

boundary condition where $r=1$: $u=0$.

Where to put these conditions, because I can put initial condition in ode45 solver, but where to put boundary condition in this case?

Comment: `ode45` doesn't solve second order equations, you have to do some more work first.

Comment: For a boundary value problem you might want to use the boundary value solvers, Matlab provides such procedures. See the documentation how to encode the boundary conditions as a function parameter.